# Python Integer Bit masking while keeping sign

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I am trying to replicate/validate bitwise arithmetic logic in Python.
I have cases where bits from the absolute value are truncated (no matter if they are 0 or 1) while the sign is preserved. This happens in various bit length representations.
**How to implement truncating bits from the absolute value also for negative integers elegantly in Python ?**

For positive integers I can easily apply a bit mask:

```
n=7; nMod=n & 0b11; print(nMod) #truncate MSB
#expected and actual: 3
```

For negative integers it does not work, probably due to the internal 2's complement and variable number of bits representation:

```
n=-7; nMod=n & 0b11; print(nMod)
#expected:-3; actual: 1
```

One could certainly analyze the absolute value, determine which bits are actually Ones and remove them by shifting left and right but my wish would be a simple one-liner like for the positive numbers.

Comment: Negate, mask, negate.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm :). Post as answer and I will accept.

Comment: However it does not work for positive numbers, so I need to check the sign first and apply different operations. Any idea for a one-liner that works regardless of the sign (of n)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `n` is the value and `mask` is the mask. You need to basically do `sign(n)*(abs(n)&mask)`. To perform `sign(n)`, you can do this `(n>0)-(n<0)`.

So here is one line,

```py
def signed_masking(n, mask):
    return ((n>0)-(n<0))*(abs(n)&mask)
```